# reading int from console

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

How can I convert a `String` array into an `int` array in java?
I am reading a stream of integer characters into a `String` array from the console, with

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for(c=0;c<str.length;c++) 
    str[c] = br.readLine();
```

where `str[]` is String typed.
I want to compare the `str[]` contents ... which can't be performed on chars (the error)
And hence I want to read `int` from the console. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(String);` is something that you want.

---

Try this:

```
int[] array = new int[size];
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length ; j++) {
                int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                array[j] = k;
        }
     }

    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Anyways,why don't you use Scanner? It'd be much easier for you if you use Scanner. :)

```
int[] array = new int[size];
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //Import java.util.Scanner for it
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length ; j++) {
                int k = in.nextInt();
                array[j] = k;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

---

Answer (score 7):

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(String s);
```

Comment: Don't forget to catch `NumberFormatException` if the `String` does not contain a parsable `int`.

Answer (score 7):

Using a scanner is much faster and hence more efficient. Also, it doesn't require you to get into the hassle of using buffered streams for input. Here's its usage:

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);  // "System.in" is a stream, a String or File object could also be passed as a parameter, to take input from

int n;    // take n as input or initialize it statically
int ar[] = new int[n];
for(int a=0;a<ar.length;a++)
  ar[a] = sc.nextInt();
// ar[] now contains an array of n integers
```

Also note that, `nextInt()` function can throw 3 exceptions as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29). Don't forget to handle them.