# How do i declare and read values into integer values?

Tags: java

I'm really new to java and i'm taking an introductory class to computer science. I need to know how to Prompt the user to user for two values, declare and define 2 variables to store the integers, and then be able to read the values in, and finally print the values out. But im pretty lost and i dont even know how to start i spent a whole day trying.. I really need some help/guidance. I need to do that for integers, decimal numbers and strings. Can someone help me?

Comment: Didn't they show you how to do this in class?

Comment: i missed the second day of lecture.... i looked on our online class but all i saw was an upcoming test :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading int from console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938389/reading-int-from-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Scanner` class to get the values from the user. For integers you should use `int`, for decimal numbers (also called real numbers) use `double` and for strings use `Strings`.

A little example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int intValue;
double decimalValue;
String textValue;

System.out.println("Please enter an integer value");
intValue = scan.nextInt(); // see how I use nextInt() for integers
System.out.println("Please enter a real number");
decimalValue = scan.nextDouble(); // nextDouble() for real numbers
System.out.println("Please enter a string value");
textValue = scan.next();    // next() for string variables

System.out.println("Your integer is: " + intValue + ", your real number is: "
                                + decimalValue + " and your string is: " + textValue);
```

If you still don't understand something, please look further into the `Scanner` class via google.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `Scanner` class :
A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.
A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

For example, this code allows a user to read a number from System.in:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scan.nextInt();
int j = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("i = "+i +" j = "+j);
```

nextInt() : -Scans the next token of the input as an int and returns the int scanned from the input.

For [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

or to get user input you can also use the **Console** class : provides methods to access the character-based console device, if any, associated with the current Java virtual machine.

```
Console console = System.console();
String s = console.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
```

or you can also use **BufferedReader** and **InputStreamReader** classes and
**DataInputStream** class to get user input .

Answer (score 1):

As you will likely continue to run into problems like this in your class and in your programming career:

Lessons on fishing.

- Learn to explore the provided tutorials through [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).
- Learn to read the Java API [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Now to the fish.

You can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. Example provided in the documentation.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
```